# How to unselect menu?

Tags: angularjs

I have this function in my controller.Problem is that i change menu based on state and when i click first time its okay..it select my menu but when i click again on that menu i want to unselect it.Is there any way to do this like toggle function??

```
 $scope.isHighLighthed = function(state) {


        if ($state.includes(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is my html:

```
    <div class="account-heading pointer" ng-class="{'active': isHighLighthed('@item.StateName')}">
    <h4 class="account-title has-sub ">
     <label class="white customSubMenu" ui-sref="@item.StateName" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@item.TransKey.ToLower()">@Translator.Translate(item.TransKey)</label>
    /h4>
  </div>
<div id="@item.TransKey.ToLower()" class="account-collapse collapse" ng-class="{'in':isHighLighthed('@item.StateName') }">
<div class="account-body">

 @foreach (var subIteam in ((MainMenuModel)item).SubMenu)
 {
   <a ui-sref="@subIteam.StateName" href="@subIteam.DisplayUrl" ng-class="{'active-link' : isHighLighthed('@subIteam.StateName')}">@Translator.Translate(subIteam.TransKey)</a>
    }
   </div>
</div>
```

So basically i need to remove active class when i click again

Comment: Please show the method that gets executed when you click the link

Comment: @MathiasF which method? im trying all with states to handle that